# How can I call rising or falling roads?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

[image]

[image]

[image]

In my language we have a word to describe that kind of roads. How can I do this in English? is there a specific word for that or I can say just 'a road that goes up'?Also in my language we can use same word to describe roads that goes down. Is this true for English? Briefly I was wondering  in US, how people describe roads that go up or down like in pictures?

Comment: no that guy is asking wavey roads. I'm asking rising or falling roads

Comment: Ascending, descending.  Rolling hills if it alternates repeatedly -- fun on a bicycle.

Comment: Some roads are built on ground which is so steep that the route of the road has to be chosen carefully so that the road is not too steep. Such roads are built at a shallow angle to the horizontal contour line. Do you want a word which encompasses all steep roads, including roads like that? Or do you want a word which specifically indicates a road which goes straight up the slope, at right angles to the contour line?

Comment: Can you edit the title, which isn't grammatical, but I'm not entirely clear what is best to correct it: maybe "What do I call rising or falling roads?".

Comment: I voted to reopen because of one conjunction, OR. Indeed, the indicated duplicate asks about roads going up AND down, whereas this question about roads going up OR down

Comment: When you say that your language has a word to describe roads which are not on flat ground do you mean (a) that your language has adjectives to describe such roads (b) that your language has one or more different nouns for roads going up or down hill (c) that your language has different adjectives or nouns for roads going up or down hillI? In English we have a number of different words for thoroughfares but they can all be subject to the same set of adjectives regarding steepness. For instance "a steep street", "a gently rising road" and so on.

Comment: @BoldBen thanks man. (a) yes we have adjectives for these kinds of roads or streets. It exactly means "steep" like u said. (b) I don't know maybe we have but there is a word which is used commonly(let say it is xxxx) we are using it in my language like I go up xxxx or I go down xxxx. And I was wondering possible translations for xxxx.(c) yes we have different usings to describe that kind of roads. And what exactly I was wondering is how an American describe that kind of roads. And thanks your comment and examples.

Comment: I think the nearest equivalent to xxxx in your comment is probably "hill". I'm British but I think Americans use it in the same way. We do literally say "I have to go uphill (or downhill) to go to work" but going uphill does not, necessarily, mean using a road or path. A hill is a geological feature but we sometimes call the side of a ridge and particularly a road up a slope "a hill". When talking about roads goingnup or down hill Americans often talk about "a grade" but that's not really something you would hear in the UK.

Comment: @BoldBen Thanks sir. If I could, I would mark this comment. Thank you for your time, but I have one more question which verb should I use with a grade go, climb, go down/up, walk down/up?

Comment: You can use all of those except "go" on its own with very little difference of meaning. There isn't, though, an antonym that I can think of for "climb" meaning "go down". We can use "ascend" and "descend" but these are rather formal. Interestingly it's perfectly normal to talk about a vehicle "climbing" a slope, grade, hill and so on.

Answer (score 6):

That would be an ***uphill*** or ***a downhill road***.

*uphill* means

> going or tending upward on or as if on a hill
>
> - an uphill road ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/uphill))

Comment: Also a road with in incline, or a grade, or a steep grade.

Comment: Or, if the hills are not too steep, an _undulating_ road.

Comment: @JohnLawler I believe it should be either "a road with an incline", or "a road with a decline". In common speech, you can also just use uphill and downhill (which are normally adverbs) as nouns, if you wish: "a road with a large uphill followed by a mid-sized downhill." Using grade, upgrade or incline in this situation, along with adjectives likes steep/gentle to describe the amount of grade would sound more technically precise to me.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, an ***upgrade*** or ***downgrade road***

upgrade:

(n.) an upward grade or slope [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upgrade)

(adj.) *US and Canadian* going or sloping upward

(adv.) *US and Canadian*  up an incline, hill, or slope

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

A **sloping** road.

> 1. *vt* to lie or cause to lie at a slanting or oblique angle
> 2. *intr*  (esp. of natural features) to follow an inclined course "many paths sloped down the hillside." [Collins reverso](https://mobile-dictionary.reverso.net/en/english-definition/sloping+road)

Comment: To do: discuss"the road slopes" vs. "the road is sloped" .